# Filter across different models by one common field in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following django model manager:

```python
class EntityManager(models.Manager):
    ...

    def filter(self, uuid, *args, **kwargs):
        entity_qs = EmptyQuerySet()
        for Model in entity_classes:
            count = Model.objects.filter(uuid=uuid, *args, **kwargs).count()
            if count:
                entity_qs = Model.objects.filter(uuid=uuid, *args, **kwargs)
                break

        return entity_qs
```

`uuid` field is a common field across different models and it is unique across them. Idea of the
code above is to get count of rows for different models and when it is positive then return actual query set that will return necessary instance on evaluation. So in worse cases we will do `len(entity_classes)` SELECT statements + 1 select on result query set evaluation.

The question is: is it possible to filter across different models by one common field with django orm with more efficient way than i do?

Comment: Seems to me that if all your models share an attribute, then they should all inherit from some parent with that attribute, (pretty sure that's one of the keys to inheritance). Then you wouldn't have to filter across multiple models.

Comment: Seems i should add that to my question. I didn't used inheritance from basic non abstract model to not produce joins. Operations with models in general are more often then getting uuid so in my case i'd prefer to avoid such inheritance.

Comment: You know this is only going to return the first model that matches?

Comment: I noted that uuid is unique across all entities, there should be only one entity for certain uuid.

Answer (score 1):

First, to try to answer your question directly: given what you've described, I don't know any way around checking each table. If you index on `uuid` that will certainly speed up the queries. Also, use `exists()` instead of `count()`.

But the fact that `uuid` is unique across all tables might be a sign that you should reorganize your schema. If you can't do away with the idea entirely, consider linking from your user model to a new model that specifies both the table and the primary key of the corresponding row.

Django has a built-in way of doing this: the `contenttypes` framework. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/contenttypes/):

> Adding a foreign key from one of your own models to ContentType allows your model
>   to effectively tie itself to another model class.... A normal ForeignKey can only
>   "point to" one other model.... The contenttypes application provides a special field
>   type (GenericForeignKey) which works around this and allows the relationship to be
>   with any model.

Comment: Thanks for the point to `.exists()`

Yes put uuid in separate table and connect it via contenttype might be interesting, i'll check it.